# Show that if p is a prime and $p>3$ then $2^{(p-2)} + 3^{(p-2)} + 6^{(p-2)}\equiv 1 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if p is a prime and $p>3$ then $2^{(p-2)} + 3^{(p-2)} + 6^{(p-2)}\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

I see that $2^{(p-2)} + 3^{(p-2)} + 6^{(p-2)}$ are inverses for 2, 3, 6 respectively but not too sure how to proceed with this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's basically because $$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} = 1,$$ and $2^{p-2}$, $3^{p-2}$, $6^{p-2}$ are the inverses of $2,3,6$ by Fermat's little theorem. To prove this rigorously, just multiply both sides by $6$, which is invertible modulo $p > 3$.